# Ejercicio Recursividad C#

Tags: c#

Estoy atascado con un ejercicio de recursividad en C#,a continuación les dejo la consigna:

-Hacer un árbol como se detalla abajo a partir del ingreso de un valor de una variable.

Ej: Ingreso 5

```
 - - - - 1

 - - - 2 2 2

 - - 3 3 3 3 3

 - 4 4 4 4 4 4 4

 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

(no se si se ve bien, pero la idea es que quede en forma de pino triangular)

Si alguien me podría dar una mano para poder resolverlo, le agradecería un montón, creo que hay algo en el planteo que no estoy pudiendo razonar.

El codigo al que pude llegar es el siguiente:

```
class Program
{
    public class Arbol
    {
        void hacerArbol(int x)
        {
            if (x > 0)
            {
                hacerArbol(x - 1);

                if (x < 5)
                {
                    Console.Write("_" + " ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(x);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                //hacerArbol(x - 1);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Arbol nuevo = new Arbol();
            nuevo.hacerArbol(5);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

No puedo lograr plantear la figura que se pide, creo que hay una parte que no me puedo imaginar como hacer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No sé si el orden de la figura importa, me refiero, a si el pino debe estar centrado o alineado a la izquierda o algo así.

Pero este código me ha funcionado para resolver un pino alineado a la izquierda :)

Su funcionamiento es sencillo.

```
public static void DrawTree(int max, int color = 0)
{
    int n = color;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        Console.Write(n.ToString() + " ");
    Console.WriteLine();

    if (color == max) return;

    DrawTree(max, n + 1);
}
```

Primero dos parametros, el primero (`max`), el número de iteraciones que formaran el pino y el último (`color`) que es un parametro por defecto el cual es 0 *(al primer intento)*, con estos dos, se dibuja a lo largo llamandose recursivamente.

```
public static void Main()
{
    DrawTree(5);
}
```

Con el código anterior, se produce la siguiente salida:

```
1 
2 2 
3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5
```

---

### EDIT: Agregada información.

Si necesitas que el arbol quede dibujado hacia el centro: Agrega la siguiente linea antes del bucle `for`:

```
 Console.Write(new string(' ', max - color));
```

Dejando el código así:

```
public static void DrawTree(int max, int color = 0)
{
    int n = color;
    Console.Write(new string(' ', max - color));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        Console.Write(n.ToString() + " ");
    Console.WriteLine();

    if (color == max) return;

    DrawTree(max, n + 1);
}
```

El cual produce la siguiente salida:

```
    1 
   2 2 
  3 3 3 
 4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: Es buena tu respuesta pero el árbol tiene que quedar centrado.
 
Lo que me marea es que para centrar el árbol hay que usar algún carácter lo que implica que hay que añadir una variable mas, que no es estática y cambia con los ciclos.
Todo esto siempre haciendo uso de técnicas recursivas.

Muchas gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: Mira el editado @user3615

Comment: Buenisimo, tal vez me estaba estructurando en solo usar ciclos recursivos y no usar ciclos for,  vamos a ver si mi profesor me acepta el uso de un ciclo for.

Comment: El método se llama a sí mismo el número de veces que tiene que realizar la tarea. Eso es recursión, el ciclo `for` está dentro de las tareas que tiene que realizar el método, por lo que es válido. Si te fijas, el ciclo solo es utilizado para pintar los caracteres en la consola.

Comment: No es necesario el bucle `for` para crear los espacios necesarios para centrar las ramas, `string` [dispone de un constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/xsa4321w(v=vs.110).aspx) al que se le puede pasar la cantidad de repeticiones de un caracter que se quiere que tenga.

Comment: simplemente denotar que me extraña que esta sea la solución marcada puesto que no cumple los requisitos iniciales, ya que en la segunda fila hay tres doses deseados y aqui se marcan solo 2 doses

Answer (score 4):

Este ejercicio de recursividad me parece bastante malo... tiene la particularidad de necesitar saber la altura de antemano para poder escribir los guiones de cada piso asi que la función

```
hacerArbol(int x)
```

no sirve; pero se puede hacer de manera diferente:

```
string hacerRama(int x, int y)
{
    // Al llegar a x = 1, finaliza la recursividad.
    if (x == 1)
        return string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("- ", y - 1)) + '1';

    // La llamada recursiva se hace en hacerRama no en hacerArbol
    return hacerRama(x - 1, y) + Environtment.NewLine + Environtment.NewLine +
           // Cada coleccion de guiones decrece a medida que bajamos ramas
           string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("- ", y - x)) +
           // El tamaño de cada rama es una secuencia de numeros impares: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9...
           string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(x.ToString() + ' ', (x * 2) - 1));
}

string hacerArbol(int x)
{
    // hacerRama es recursiva
    return hacerRama(x, x);
}
```

La cadena resultante de llamar `hacerArbol(5)` seria exactamente el que pusiste en el ejemplo.

El truco consiste concatenar las cadenas a la inversa poniendo la primera llamada a `hacerRama` al final de la cadena.

PD: A partir de números de dos dígitos no funciona.

Comment: Sobre este ejercicio, no entiendo el por qué pintar los números, precisamente por eso que mencionas.

Comment: @NaCl no entiendo a que te refieres :'(

Comment: me refiero a que no entiendo el por qué pintar los números en la consola, esa es la razó por la cual el algoritmo no funciona con numeros de 2 digitos.

Comment: @NaCl ah vale! Bueno yo entiendo que se debe pintar por la consola como parte del ejercicio; habitualmente los ejercicios para *principiantes* consisten en precisamente eso.

Answer (score 0):

Algo asi tal vez podria funcionar...

Cambia el valor de la variable `int maxNumberIterate = 5;` y  ahi estaria tu ejercicio resuelto.

Codigo:

```
using System;           
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int countNumber =0;
        int repeatNumber = 0;
        int maxNumberIterate =6;
        string firstlines= string.Empty;
        firstlines= firstlines.PadLeft(maxNumberIterate ,'-');
        Console.WriteLine(firstlines + "1");
        for (countNumber=1; countNumber < maxNumberIterate; countNumber++)
        {
             repeatNumber ++;
             string lines=string.Empty;
             string numbers= string.Empty;
             lines= lines.PadLeft(maxNumberIterate - (countNumber ),'-');
             numbers= numbers.PadLeft( repeatNumber * 2  , char.Parse((countNumber + 1).ToString()));
             Console.WriteLine(lines + (countNumber + 1).ToString()+ numbers);
        }
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/vSs425

Comment: Hola manuel, aunque el enlace que colocas, puede resolver el problema, es bueno que coloques el código aquí además del enlace. Porque muchas veces los enlaces dejan de funcionar con el tiempo o son movidos a otra url y tu respuesta ya no tendría sentido.

Comment: Gracias por la observacion

Comment: Si, edita tu pregunta y coloca el código también :) , Saludos!